# Issue with sliding background on Ubuntu18.04(Virtualbox)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a VirtualBox Vm and I'm trying to code a very simple game. I have a problem with the sliding background I'm trying to use.
After the first image cycle (the starting background and the first reset) the background glitches and shows no image. Could it be a problem related to the fact that I'm running this .py program on a virtual machine? Or did I use the wrong code? I'd like to have the background image continuously cycle, and not just once.
Here's the code I'm running:

```
import pygame
import os

size = width, height = 750, 422
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

img_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd())
background_image = pygame.image.load('background.jpg').convert()
bg_image_rect = background_image.get_rect()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)

pygame.display.set_caption("BallGame")

class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
        self.image_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image_rect.x
        self.image_rect.y
        self.facing = 'LEFT'

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and self.image_rect.y < 321:
            self.facing = 'DOWN'
            self.image_rect.y += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_UP] and self.image_rect.y > 0:
            self.facing = 'UP'
            self.image_rect.y -= dist
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.image_rect.x < 649:
            self.facing = 'RIGHT'
            self.image_rect.x += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT] and self.image_rect.x > 0:
            self.facing = 'LEFT'
            self.image_rect.x -= dist

    def draw(self, surface):
        if self.facing == "RIGHT":
            surface.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False),(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))
        elif self.facing == "DOWN":
            surface.blit(pygame.image.load("ball_down.png"),(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))
        if self.facing == "UP":
            surface.blit(pygame.image.load("ball_up.png"),(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))
        elif self.facing == "LEFT":
            surface.blit(self.image,(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((750, 422))

ball = Ball()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.music.load("bg_music.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

running = True
while running:
    esc_key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if esc_key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            running = False

    ball.handle_keys()

    screen.blit(background_image, bg_image_rect)
    screen.blit(background_image, bg_image_rect.move(bg_image_rect.width, 0))
    bg_image_rect.move_ip(-2, 0)
    if bg_image_rect.right == 0:
        bg_image_rect.x == 0


    ball.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue lies when you are checking the current position of your background, and resetting it:

```
if bg_image_rect.right == 0:
    bg_image_rect.x == 0
```

First, the `if` statement assumes that your `bg_image_rect.right` is going to perfectly hit the `0` position as it's scrolling. It is possible based on the combination of window size and background size the scrolling might look like:
`13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1, -1, -3, -5`. Which means `right == 0` will never be `True`.

Second, you have a typo in your assignment of `x`. `bg_image_rect.x == 0` is *comparing* the two values. You need `bg_image_rect.x = 0`.

This section needs to change to:

```
if bg_image_rect.right <= 0:
    bg_image_rect.x = 0
```

Comment: Thank you @alxwrd it worked flawlessly, and thank you for the explanation.